# Any grunt packages exist for including html partials from an external web source?

Tags: curl, gruntjs, include

I looked and I don't seem to see any grunt modules that can accommodate a url (http://domain.com/route) when pulling partials.

all of them seem to only pull from the local directory.

Ideally I could do something along the lines of

```
@@indlude(http://localhost:3000/something/else)
```

and it would pull in the html from that url.

I am using php to render partials with "good" fake content. It would save me a step if grunt could pull the rendered resources in when building the "dist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying you can trigger generation of the source HTML markup by hitting a list of URLs. You want to save this generated source in a bunch of individual files so you can use them as template files (partials).

You could do this with [grunt-curl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-curl), for example.

From there, you should be able to put something like this into your `Gruntfile.js` configuration file:

```
'curl-dir': {
  'task-name': {
    src: [
      'http://localhost:3000/something/else/a.html',
      'http://localhost:3000/something/else/b.html'
    ],
    dest: 'location/to/save/files'
  }
}
```

That grunt task should then save the markup source to the directory you specify by running the grunt task directly: `grunt curl-dir:task-name`.

Comment: not exactly, but that will work as well. I'll save them down as partials then use  includes to get them where they need to go